# Change AppCompat SearchView suggestion background

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-widget, searchview

I want to set the background of the dropdown suggestions of the SearchView in my Theme style. I don't want to do this via layout files, because I want the OS to handle the selection backgrounds themselves. Setting the background programmatically removed list selectors, and I want to avoid that.

[image: example]

This is what I have right now. I want the background of the rows to be white. What do I have to change in my `styles.xml` to achieve that?

PS: i removed the text on the suggestions myself, so it looks like a big dark block.

Comment: Try setting a new style for the AutoCompletTextView widget in your custom theme and in that style change the background(popupBackground is the attribute).

Comment: @Luksprog that was it man thank you. I have not been able to find any pointers that I had to style AutoCompleteTextView with that particular attribute. [It did cause me to find a bug in Android](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=155891&thanks=155891&ts=1424820365). If you want to add this as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `SearchView` has its popup based on a standard styled `AutoCompleteTextView` so you could change the standard style for this widget in your custom theme to obtain the background change. So in the custom theme override the `autoCompleteTextViewStyle` attribute to point to a new style in which you have to override the `popupBackground` with the desired background.

Comment: Would you also tell me how do I change `textColor` of the listItem ? Should I modify `ListViewSelector` ?

Comment: What You say I am not Understand Please say clearly what you say in coding form

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Comment: @Luksprog, you should provide a sample code to make the answer much more cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by using

```
int autoCompleteTextViewID = getResources().getIdentifier("search_src_text", "id", getPackageName());
mSearchAutoCompleteTextView = mSearchView.findViewById(autoCompleteTextViewID);
mSearchAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownBackgroundResource(R.color.white); // Setting background color of the suggestion drop down list
```

Comment: While this does work, the text in the list remains the same color (white) so you can't see anything. So, changing a style is more appropriate.

Comment: @John61590 you would use a custom layout for the list item

Comment: actually, there is no need. You can override dropDownItemStyle in your main theme and change the text color there.
        `<item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/MyDropDownItemStyle</item>
<style name="MyDropDownItemStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item></style>`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but here is what worked for me.

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">       <item name="autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/MyAutoCompleteTextView</item>              <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/MyDropDownItemStyle</item> </style>`

Below changes the suggestion dropdown background color on light theme.

`<style name="MyAutoCompleteTextView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.AutoCompleteTextView"><item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item></style>`

Below changes the suggestion dropdown text color to black on light theme.

`<style name="MyDropDownItemStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner"><item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item></style>`

Answer (score -2):

```
searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb( 164, 200, 57, 1));
```

Or:

```
searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(116,0,0));
```

insert this in:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

Comment: This only sets the whole searchview in the toolbar to another color, not the dropdown in question.